# Tapping on a checkmark on the UITableViewCell Edit Mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am in the `tableView` editing mode. I have a checkmark in the left side of the tableView.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is getting called each time I tap on the check mark.

When i uncheck the checkmark (i.e. tap on the cell again) the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is **NOT** called again.

Anyone knows solution to this ?

Perhaps another method that gets called each time a check mark is pressed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is only called when a cell is *selected*. If you want to know when it's deselected, use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED ! Dammit. Never knew this exited.